# How to set video record resolution in Windows Phone 8.

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to capture video using a custom app on windows phone 8.

I am following the guidelines as per the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394041%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Controlling) here.

I am clueless on how to set the resolutoin for the captured video. Currently it is being recorded at a resolution of 640x480 by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `VideoCaptureDevice` class which is the Windows Phone 7.5 API for recording video. That API *by design* is limited to 640*480.

If you want more control over the recorded video, you should use the new Windows Phone 8 API: [`AudioVideoCaptureDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which has a [`SetCaptureResolutionAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice.setcaptureresolutionasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method. Of course, it will require a Windows Phone 8 device.

Comment: Thanks. I had just come across this API even myself.