# How to record video using AudioVideoCptureDevice in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, stream, video-recording, front-camera

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) its stated that I can record video using `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` but there is no sample or help provided.

I need to do the following things:

 - record the video into a stream **DONE**

 - display a thumbnail of video recorded (can be a frame captured while video recording) **DONE**

 - replay the video recorded **DONE**

 - change resolution and type of camera (front/back) **DONE**

How to achieve this? Are there any samples? I am unable to find them. Please help me.

**DONE**

 - record the video into a stream

 - replay the video recorded

 - change resolution and type of camera (front/back)

 - display a thumbnail of video recorded (can be a frame captured while video recording)

**NEW PROBLEMS**

 - front camera video is mirror inverted. I am able to change this while recording using transform but the actual video is still mirrored.

**UPDATE**

 - calculate the size of the recording video and display it. Its not working. Stream.Size is giving random values.

Any thoughts on solving these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the problem of Displaying a Thumbnail of the video recording...there is an event called PreviewFrameAvailable on the AudioVideoCaptureDevice.  I think if you setup this event handler it will tell you when the data is available to get a preview (image/thumbnail) of the video.

There are also 3 methods for grabbing a byte array of a preview image (GetPreviewBufferARGB, GetPreviewBufferY, GetPreviewBufferYCbCr).  All three of these methods return a byte[] of the pixel data for the image in the corresponding format (ex: GetPreviewBufferARGB should return the raw bytes of a raw bitmap in ARGB format).  After getting the byte array of the preview data you should be able to encode it as a PNG or JPEG or whatever compressed image format you prefer.  Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry No, I've only worked briefly with the rear camera so far.  Best of Luck to you!

Comment: btw do you know how to display the recorded video size? randomaccessstream.size is throwing random values for Nokia devices, works well in htc.

Answer (score 1):

The basics of using the Windows Phone 8 camera are covered here...

[Advanced photo capture for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[How to save a picture captured with the new camera’s API in the camera roll in Windows Phone 8](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-save-a-picture-captured-with-the-new-cameras-api-in-the-camera-roll-in-windows-phone-8/)

[How to set video record resolution in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522290/how-to-set-video-record-resolution-in-windows-phone-8)

[How to set advanced properties for video recording in WP8](http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Code/2013/05/28/how-to-set-advanced-properties-for-video-recording-in-wp8)

**Note:** there are issues when getting the supported resolutions of the front camera on [some Lumia devices](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Camera_APIs_may_use/report_incorrect_supported_resolution_on_some_Lumia_devices_%28Known_Issue%29)

Comment: They dont use AudioVideoCaptureDevice and there is no sample for front camera.

Comment: I've updated the links - and you're right, there isn't much on the front camera specifically but once the `CameraSensorLocation.Front` is specified, the regular camera API applies. Also, one question at a time :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But now only one problem remains. Front camera recording is mirror inverted. Trying to crack that.

Comment: @MilanAggarwal did you find any solution for "Front camera records mirror inverted video"..? I'm facing the same issue and unable to find solution.

Comment: Actually I didnt, for now I am just rotating the frame, so that the recording person doesn't see the inversion. While playback using the inbuilt media player, inversion is observed.

Comment: ohkay.. but actually i'm not going to play the video in the app instead need to send it to server..! :/ can you answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984325/rotate-video-stream-wp8 
anyway, thanks for quick response.

Comment: @MilanAggarwal I found the solution for mirror inverted video recording by `front-camera`. check my answer in this post. kudos..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of mirror inverted video recording through `Front-Camera`:

the one line that solved my problem is:

```
//here videoCapture is AudioVideoCaptureDevice object

videoCapture.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation, -90);
```

**Full Code:**

XAML code

```
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasLayoutRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5"
            Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
            Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
            Margin="-160 0 0 0">

        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rt" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>

        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush" />
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
```

BackEnd C# code

```
    // in any specific method or event handler write
    // the below code while initializing the Front camera

    private AudioVideoCaptureDevice videoCapture = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Front, new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480));
    videoCapture.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation, -90);
    rt.Angle = -90;
    videoBrush.SetSource(videoCapture);
```

This piece of code helped me after tens of efforts..!