# record video by front-camera - WP8 - C#

Tags: windows-phone-8, video, rotation, front-camera

My windows phone app needs to record a video from front-camera and send it to the server through a webservice.

Here while I'm trying to record video from `front-camera`, I'm getting `mirror inverted video`. Means front-camera records 180 degree rotated video.

what i think probably the only solution of it is to rotate the recorded video stream to 180 degree back.

**Question:**

- is there any other solution to record proper video by front-camera in `wp8`?
- if not, how to rotate the video stream 180 degree? any `c#` API to do it..?

**Edit:**

Here is code that I'm using:

**XAML code for `VideoBrush`**

```xml
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasLayoutRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5"
            Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
            Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
            Margin="-160 0 0 0">
        <!--Background="Transparent"-->

        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush" />
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rt" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>

    </Canvas>
```

**Initializing camera**

```cs
    public async void InitializeVideoRecorder()
    {
        try
        {
            if (videoCapture == null)
            {
                // below line of code will detect if "Front Camera" is available or not
                // if availble, then open it or it will open "Back Camera"

                videoCapture = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(
                    AudioVideoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Front) ? CameraSensorLocation.Front : CameraSensorLocation.Back,
                    new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480));

                videoCapture.RecordingFailed += videoCapture_RecordingFailed;

                videoCapture.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation, videoCapture.SensorRotationInDegrees);

                // Initialize the camera if it exists on the phone.
                if (videoCapture != null)
                {
                    videoBrush.SetSource(videoCapture);
                    if (!AudioVideoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Front))
                    {
                        rt.Angle = videoCapture.SensorRotationInDegrees;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rt.Angle = -(videoCapture.SensorRotationInDegrees);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to load Camera. Please try again later.", App.appName, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            (new WebServices()).catchExceptions(ex);
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

**Starting VideoCapture**

```cs
    private async Task StartVideoRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            // Gets the application data folder
            StorageFolder applicationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFolder transfersFolder = await (await applicationFolder.GetFolderAsync("Shared")).GetFolderAsync("Transfers");

            // Create the file specified in the application data folder
            videoFileName = selectedQue.response.template_id + "_" + selectedQue.response.id + "_" + selectedQue.response.invite_id +".mp4";
            StorageFile storageFile = await transfersFolder.CreateFileAsync(videoFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            // Open a file stream, ready to write video data
            randomAccessStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

            // Video recording to the specified stream
            await videoCapture.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(randomAccessStream);
            isRecordingStarted = true;

            //timer = "0:00";
            tbTimer.Text = "0:00";
            dt.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            (new WebServices()).catchExceptions(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this in portrait mode, or landscape mode? Perhaps you could update your question to include the relevent code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I've added the code. actually I want it in Portrait Mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem after 24 hours of efforts with below solution.

The line of code that causing issue by rotating video was below.

```
videoCapture.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation, videoCapture.SensorRotationInDegrees);
```

here videoCapture is object of AudioVideoCaptureDevice

While using front camera, we need to invert the rotation of `cameraSensor`.

So I've used the above same code (mentioned in question) with one tiny modification in this `videoCapture.SetProperty` line of code. the correct line of code is as below.

```
videoCapture.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation, -(videoCapture.SensorRotationInDegrees));
```

I just inverted the `videoCapture.SensorRotationInDegrees` by adding one minus sign (-) before it.

Hope this helps all..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the past, it was just a barcode scanner app that I coded up to fulfill a functional requirement.  I put the transform on the `<VideoBrush>`.

```XAML
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Canvas x:Name="cam_canvas" Width="480" Height="480">                
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="cam_video_brush" Stretch="None">
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="90" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs.. I tried that but didn't helped..!
still captured video by `Front-Camera` is inverted (180 degree rotated)..!
any other solution on how to rotate any video's stream.